# Read image file hex values and print to file

Tags: c

I am absolutely new to C, learning from a book. I have been searching on the net for how to read and write hex values but I can't find what I am looking for.

Basically I want to read an image file like jpg and write it out to a file verbatim, but my code doesn't do it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned long txt;
    FILE *myimg, *img;

    myimg=fopen("myimg.jpg","w");
    fclose(myimg);
    myimg=fopen("myimg.jpg","rb+");
    img=fopen("img.jpg","rb");txt=0;
    printf("Start");
    while(!feof(img))
    {
        if(img==NULL)
        {
            printf("WTF1");
        }
        txt=fgetc(img);
        fprintf(myimg,"%x",txt);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

The output file is different in size and when I look at it in a hex editor, there is no similarity. Can you tell me how it is done?

Comment: Step 1: Learn how to properly format your code (in source and on SO). You're not doing anyone any favors by not using any spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `CHAR_BITS==8`, each `char` holds a value in the range [0..255] (or [-128..127] if it is signed).  This is represented in hex by [0x00..0xff].  Values between 0 and 15 can be represented as hex in a single character; other values will need two characters to represent a single `char` as hex.

```
fprintf(myimg,"%x",txt);
```

write the value of your `char` as hex.  For values outside the range [0..15], it'll need to write 2 characters to represent a single `char`.  (e.g. if `txt==16`, formatting it as hex will write the characters `1` then `0` to file.)

You need to use the `%c` format specifier instead

```
fprintf(myimg,"%c",txt);
```

Alternatively, it'd be clearer if you used [fputc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fputc)

```
fputc(myimg,txt);
```

Comment: wow! thanx a ton!! so what is the %x used for? (tried to upvote u, but need 15+ rep. thanx tho)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a bit more detail.  In short, `%x` gives a textual representation of a single `char`.  While you can't yet upvote, you can [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) if your question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is different from what you read.
You read a char, but you write a long value in text mode, they are quite different.
If you open your output file in a normal text editor and open your input file in a hex editor, they should look the same.
Just use fputc() instead of fprintf, you should get what you want.